# Plotly poor performance. How to get around?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

We are using `plot_ly` to visualize scientific data. It works like a charm when we plot "small" datasets. However, when using huge datasets it becomes extremely slow. We would like to know if there are some tricks to increase the performance, for example: disabling hovers or avoiding rescaling when zooming.

We use ggplotly to translate from our ggplot code but we already tried to use directly `plot_ly %>% add_polygons` and `plot_ly(..., type="scatter", mode="lines", fill="toself")` with no gain in terms of performance.

Any idea about that?

Example code where `plotly` becomes slows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

myfakedatagenerator <- function(sz){
    aux <- data.frame(
        Value = factor(sample(c("abc", "qwe", "xyz", "asd"), size=sz, replace=TRUE)),
        Resource = factor(sample(28, size=sz, replace=TRUE)),
        Duration = sample(20, size=sz, replace = TRUE)
    )
    aux <- aux %>% group_by(Resource) %>% mutate(End=cumsum(Duration))
    aux <- aux %>% group_by(Resource) %>% mutate(Start=End-Duration)
    aux 
}

tmp <- myfakedatagenerator(10000)

gg <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Start, y=Resource)) + 
      geom_rect(aes(xmin=Start, xmax=End,
                    ymin=as.numeric(Resource)-.4,
                    ymax=as.numeric(Resource)+.4,
                    fill=Value,
                    a=Start,
                    b=Value,
                    c=Duration
                    )) +
      scale_x_continuous("") + scale_y_discrete()

ggplotly(gg)
```

Comment: How big is "huge"? The issue is obviously since the chart is interactive, the JS has to store the data in the chart object. If you're passing millions of rows it's going to be slow, no way around it.

Comment: As I put in the example code, 10 000 rectangles is already huge for plotly considering a machine with a i7 processor and 16gb of RAM.

Comment: Plotly is essentially just a D3.js wrapper and in order to get the interactivity the JS chart has to store the data in the object. Just compare the performance of your `gg` object and the call to `ggplotly(gg)`. I don't think there's a feasible way around it other than to limit the scope of your data set.

Comment: @Zach I understand your point but when using geom_segment with the same data set, the performance is much better. So, it seems that is not a problem related to store the data (only 0.3 Mb for a 10 000 lines df as in my example). 
`ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Start, y=Resource)) + geom_segment(aes(x=Start, xend=End, y=Resource, yend=Resource, color=Value, size=3)) +
+ scale_x_continuous("") + scale_y_discrete()`

Comment: Not entirely sure if it helps, but have you tried switching to the "scattergl" type? Apparently the slowing is caused by the SVG implementation and a known issue. For reference see: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/741